# How to separate link items with pipeline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, pipeline

This is my first time posting a question here.

I am working with twitter bootstrap on a website design. I have to create the navigation menu such that the items listed there will be separated with pipeline. I have found another similar question here - [Add a pipe separator after items in an unordered list unless that item is the last on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171699/add-a-pipe-separator-after-items-in-an-unordered-list-unless-that-item-is-the-la) and I used that, but the items are not separated as they are supposed to.

What I need to get: http://prntscr.com/4br2lb

After implementing the code from the post I found here I get this: http://prntscr.com/4br2yj

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top header-menu">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderMenuCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-middle navbar-text" style="float:none;margin: 0 auto; display: table;table-layout: fixed;">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AUTO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LIFE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HEALTH</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MORE...</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul li { 
float: left; }
ul li:after {
content: "|"; padding: 0 .5em; }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle.

Comment: Do you need to support IE8 (which doesn't recognize `:last-child`)?

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a border for each `li` except the last instead? E.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ahtu4ndp/)

```
ul li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right:1px solid grey;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Otherwise, you will likely need to add positioning to your `:after` psuedo elements or change the display to `inline-block` - though its hard to say without being able to replicate your issue with the provided code.

Answer (score 1):

switching the `a` tags to inline blocks fixed it

```
div.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li:after {
    content: "|";
}
ul li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ufu26k/)