# How to hide last | with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML `ul li` like this:

```
<ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-356">
      <a href="http://example.com/link1/">Title 1</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-357">
      <a href="http://example.com/link2/">Title 2</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-358">
      <a href="http://example.com/link3/">Title 3</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

which output like this

```
Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 |
```

So throught CSS I want to hide last `|`. I tried this but it is hidding all the `|`

```
#menu-footer-menu .f_sep:last-child{display:none}
```

I want the final output like this

```
Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3
```

Please Note: my question is not related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171699/add-a-pipe-separator-after-items-in-an-unordered-list-unless-that-item-is-the-la) because there it is been adding `|` through, but I already has pipe `|` in my HTML so I just want to hide the last occurrence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a pipe separator after items in an unordered list unless that item is the last on a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171699/add-a-pipe-separator-after-items-in-an-unordered-list-unless-that-item-is-the-la)

Comment: #menu-footer-menu li:last-child

Comment: @marmeladze: please read my _Please Note_ section. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Here is the correct answer:

```
#menu-footer-menu li:last-child .f_sep{ display:none }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#menu-footer-menu li:last-child .f_sep{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use this CSS**

```
#menu-footer-menu li:last-child .f_sep{display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ul li:last-child span {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better still use more semantic markup and display the divider with css

```css
#menu-footer-menu{list-style:none; padding:0;}

#menu-footer-menu li {display:inline-block;}

#menu-footer-menu li:not(:last-child):after
{
  content: "|";  
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-356">
      <a href="http://example.com/link1/">Title 1</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-357">
      <a href="http://example.com/link2/">Title 2</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-358">
      <a href="http://example.com/link3/">Title 3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The advantage of this, is you can just change the divider with CSS

Comment: I cannot do this because plugin is generating this code, So I have to remove it through CSS only; but thanks for your help. I'll use this approach if I have to make the `ul li` by myself.

Answer (score -1):

You are close to it. Just go with Li elements.

```css
li:last-child span{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-356">
      <a href="http://example.com/link1/">Title 1</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-357">
      <a href="http://example.com/link2/">Title 2</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-358">
      <a href="http://example.com/link3/">Title 3</a>
      <span class="f_sep">|</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```