# How to style the vertical bar i.e. "|"?

Tags: css

How do I style the vertical bar i.e. "|"? I need to vary the width and the height of the "|".

This is what I am trying to do.

```
<a href="link1"> Link 1 </a> | <a href="link2"> Link 2 </a>
```

Comment: You want to style a character in CSS?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski. I basically wanted a seprator between links. Am i going in the wrong direction?

Comment: You could use bold and increase the font size but a better alternative maybe to use a right or left border instead.

Comment: @Ashish Please provide a code sample of what you are trying to do. You may want to use padding and borders instead of a separator character.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski. Please see I have updated my question.

Comment: @Ashish I have added an answer that may help you.

Comment: Try this out

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11964666/699695

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put it in an element, and style the element:

```
<span class="bar">|</span>
```

In your style sheet, for example:

```
.bar { font-size: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't be using the pipe  (`|`) as a separator, use css instead.

Say the anchors were in a div, with id equal to `breadcrumbs`, like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>​
```

You could then add separators between them with a couple css rules, like this:

```
#breadcrumbs a {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-right: 5px solid green;
}

#breadcrumbs a:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}​
```

You could vary the size, style and color of the separator with the `border-right: 5px solid green` rule.  [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/kQTZA/2/)(updated) in action.  [Here's some documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) on border styling.

The second rule with `:last-child` prevents an extra separator after the last element.

To vary the height of the separator, you would change the `padding` on the first rule.

**By popular demand, a list version:**

If you put the links in a list:

```
<ul id="breadcrumb-list">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>​
```

And use rules like this:

```
ul#breadcrumb-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    border-right: 1px dotted blue;
}

ul#breadcrumb-list li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

You can use a `ul` to markup your list of links for better semantics. You have to add the `inline-block` to put them on one line, `li` is by default a block level element.

I've also shown a different style you can achieve by varying the padding and border rules.

Comment: I would upvote this if you were using a ul instead of a div with a bunch of a's thrown in.

Comment: Then upvote the answer that does that.  Why do you prefer that way?  What's wrong with a div with a "bunch of a's"?  Do you agree this is better than using pipes?

Comment: For best accessibility, you should always have something separating links, be it white-space,commas or having them inside list items.

That way, your markup will still be intelligible in other contexts, be it an accessibility technology, an rss feed, or whatever.

Comment: I get that it is semantically better to use a `li` to markup a list.  But this does what he's looking for, and with just two simple selectors and a total of three declarations.

Comment: @reisio, I've added an example with a list.

Comment: Mmm, if I wanted you to offer multiple options as if a bunch of random a's in a div were as good as a ul, I *would have* voted for the other one.

Answer (score 7):

`|` is a character, and as such, takes any stylings that you might apply to text.  I get the impression though, that you might be trying to use `|` to construct a box border.  If that is the case, you're much better off styling a block level element to have a border that attempting to use characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really style individual characters easily with css, unless that's the only character in your element. If it's in a textarea you have no hope. If it isn't, you have hope: you have to manually augment it with `<span class="specialBar">...</span>` tags whenever it occurs in the text you want to style it in.

You can also just use another unicode vertical-bar character which is more to your liking.

---

> *edit*, In response to:
>
> "I basically wanted a seprator between links. Am i going in the wrong direction? – original poster"

Ideally you would use spans, which you can shape with CSS to emulate a thin vertical line:

**emulate-with-a-span technique - ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs3Mc/)):**

```
.linkSeparator {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:-1em; /*value should be (height-1em)/2*/
    height:3em; width:0.25em;
    background-color:grey;
    margin-left:0.5em; margin-right:0.5em;
}​

link1<span class="linkSeparator"></span>link2<span class="linkSeparator">...
```

**images technique:**

You could also use images (less elegant, won't go into detail).

**sibling selector technique - ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XfZ62/)):**

You can also set the `border-left` on all links which aren't the first. According to the w3c spec on [CSS2 adjacency selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), "`E + F` Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E." Therefore:

```
.separatedLinks a+a {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}

<??? class="separatedLinks">
    <a href="...">link1</a>
    <a href="...">link2</a>
    <a href="...">link3</a>
</???>
```

You might be able to find more examples at this google hit: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html