# prevent parent li + li carrying to child

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using this on my nav menu to separate the list items

```
nav li + li:before{
    content: " | ";
}
```

This puts a bar between each list item, it doesn't put the bar before the first element. And using the :before pseudo selector, it doesn't put one at the end.
(as suggested here [Separators For Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688791/separators-for-navigation/11574821#11574821))

However, I want to prevent this from carrying through to child list items.

e.g. `nav ul li ul li`

I've tried `content:none;` and `content:"";` on the child but they still display in the sub-menu.

Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative without overwriting, using the Child Combinator (`>`):

```
nav > ul > li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
}
```

The Child Combinator selects an element if it is a direct child of another element (and not a grandchild of that element).

Answer (score 2):

Ah - I found the answer!

```
nav ul li li:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: This does work, and well done! But it's better to use more-specific selectors, rather than have to over-write everything you've specified previously. If only because it's more efficient, and less complex when you try to subtly amend styles later (and have to work out *why* something isn't cascading).