# Using li + li for nav separator clears <li> background after first item

Tags: html, css

I'm using a  for horizontal navigation, and thanks to the question: [Separators For Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688791/separators-for-navigation/5688928), I read about a good way to setup image-based item separators using the `li + li` (pseudo?) selector.

In my code, I'm defining a background-image for the `<li>` tags, but once I added the `li + li` code, the separators appeared, but the backgrounds on all `li` tags after the first have disappeared. If I remove the `#nav-items li+li` code, the backgrounds on all items restore (but I have no separators, obviously)

(screenshot)
[image: list item background disappearing scereenshot]

My code looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav-items">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
  etc...
</ul>
```

and my css:

```
#nav-items {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-item {
    display: list-item; 
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 39px;
    background: url('../images/top-nav-bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#nav-items li+li {
    background:url('../images/top-nav-separator.png') no-repeat top left; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: li+li after first li remaining all LI's will take your separator as a background... you have to choose different mark up...

Comment: I would try setting `top-nav-bg.png` background to the element `a` and `top-nav-separator.png` background to the element `li` ... or viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav-items li+li:before{
    background:url('../images/top-nav-separator.png') no-repeat top left; 
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    width:3px   /* your image width */
    height:57px   /* your image height */
}
```