# Html border-separator in header between ul-li tags

Tags: css, html, header, border

Look at my problem:

**Now i have:**
[image]

**What i need to do:**
[image]

I tryed to do with border, but nothing happends.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ul id="tabMenu">
<li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab1"><div class="dropdown_text">поиск по производителю</div></a></div></li>
<li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab2"><div class="dropdown_text">поиск по назначению</div></a></div></li>
<li class="dropdown"><div id="menu_logo"></div></li>
<li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab3"><div class="dropdown_text">кабинет</div></a></div></li>
<li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab5"><div class="dropdown_text">сравнение</div></a></div></li>
<li class="dropdown"><div>
<span id="more_search"></span><a class="tab4" href="/emarket/cart/"><div class="dropdown_text">покупки</div></a>
</div></li>
</ul>
```

**Here is CSS:**

```
ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
color: #ccc;
white-space: nowrap;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 55px;
}

ul li a div.dropdown_text {
display: inline-block;
}

div.site_info ul li a.tab1  (etc for a.tab2, a.tab3, a.tab4) {
float: left;
margin-left: 89px;
background: url(/img/new_desing/producers.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Help me please to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually you might want the separator, you might want a shadow? always explain what you want in your questions

Comment: If possible can you create a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: you can use gradient background color. see http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I don't see where you're setting a border in any of your pasted code.

Comment: Sorry guys, i need the separator

Answer (score 3):

if its shadow you wanted then apply this style to your `div`

```
box-shadow: 0px -3px 5px #888888;
```

or change the values till u get that effect..

**Edit**

If you want to get shadow effect inside your `div` then use

```
box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 5px #888888;
```

**Edit**

For separator use this

```
nav li + li:before{
content: " | ";
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

i got this through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688791/separators-for-navigation) link

Comment: This will cause issues with older versions of IE. I reccommend an image seperator or a border

Answer (score 0):

try applying border to

```
ul li {
display: inline-block;
border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: and what about the last li ? You forgot to add the "last" css for the last tab to be border:none;

Comment: yes I forget last child,
ul li:last-child {
display: inline-block;
border-right:none;
}

Comment: its doesnt work, because i need to have some space between li and border

Comment: So thats padding.. padding:0 Xpx 0 Xpx

Comment: @GeorgePirkulov:
ul li {
display: inline-block;
border-right:1px solid #000;
padding:5px;
}