# Navigation separators using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create separators using CSS, for keeping it semantic, and removing styles from content.

However, I wanted to have a border bottom below each `<li>` item. The `:before` selector however, extends the width of the `<li>` element, and it is creating an inconsistent border.

I've tried answers from [Separators For Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688791/separators-for-navigation), which uses a similar approach as mine, and gives the same problems.

This is my navigation (tab-based) below

```
<nav class="innerNav">
    <ul>
        <li>One </li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and my CSS

```
.innerNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.innerNav li:before {
    content: "|";
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.innerNav li:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XFd6D/

Comment: li:not(::first-child) {border-left: 1px solid #000;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you are using `:before` pseudo which generates the content virtually, still it is counted in the element, and hence your element extends.

Inorder to fix that, use `margin-left` for the `li` to space them up first, and then, use `position: absolute;` for the pseudo content and then use `left: -8px;` to position it correctly.

Make sure you use `position: relative;` for the `li` elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XFd6D/2/)

```
.innerNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.innerNav li:before {
    content: "|";
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    color: blue;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.innerNav li:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}
```

---

The other way you can do is to encapsulate the text of the `li` in a `span` element, and than assign `border-bottom` to `span` element rather than using it for an `li`

**Using span**

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XFd6D/12/)

Change your DOM like

```
<ul>
    <li><span>One</span> </li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><span>Four</span></li>
</ul>
```

And associated CSS to...

```
.innerNav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.innerNav li span {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.innerNav li:before {
    content: "|";
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.innerNav li:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, nailed it, I went with the second approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy58f/1/) should work with IE8 and higher.
Kind of like the approach of Mr. Alien, but a bit shorter and with a border instead of using a pipe.

```
.innerNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    margin-right: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.innerNav li + li:before {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.5em;
    top: 0;
}
```

Problem could be whitespace between your `<li>`, [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) more information about that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I preferred Mr. Alien's second approach, since I don't have to do a `position` modifications to achieve it.