# CSS separator for navigation in Wordpress

Tags: css, separator

On my test site http://witthotel.perfectlysimple.org/about/ I'm trying to put a separator between the different nav items.

I found several suggestions on stackoverflow ( [Separators For Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688791/separators-for-navigation) ), but none seemed to work for me somehow. Since I'm not allowed to ask more questions in the same thread, I started this one:

I started out with this solution:

```
.nav-header li + li {
    background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```

Unfortunately, even when I put in the full separator of the transparent gif, it wouldn't show up at all. The URL was correct though, since I tried it in a browser tab first.

Then I tried the following code:

```
.nav-header li + li:before{
    content: ".";
}
```

However, as you can see, the dot sits above the nav items. Any suggestions on how I can make it sit in between them?

Thanks.

Comment: ... Have you considered `border` or `border-left`?

Comment: Are you trying to add white space or a visible separator?

Comment: Exactly how transparent is the gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your css style:

```
.nav-header li + li:before{
content: ".";
position: relative;
float: left;
top: 11px;
```

}